# Automatically download txt document response

Tags: python, html

I am currently working on a python project and I would like to know how to serve a txt file to a browser. Ex: Accessing page.html will make a get request for a file with the same name to download. No FE processing is needed for the received file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the MIME type of the content. Take a look at MDN docs provided below.
[the list of current content types accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types?fbclid=IwAR0gPmy2j2e1fTE6sUIWtGf-MvHtH5joTCjQ_atkmJrhD1V-rPTxd5p9n-M)

One option that i would recommend it's application/octet-stream.